# NDSolve problem with matrix valued function

Tags: differential-equations

I got a strange problem when using `NDSolve` to solve a matrix value function

```
σ[t] = {{σx[t], σxy[t]}, {σyx[t], σy[t]}}
```

when I try to solve it in a compact form.

Here is the initialization code:

```
Clear[t]
F = {{1, t}, {0, 1}};
LL = D[F, t].Inverse[F]; 
DD = 1/2 (LL + Transpose[LL]);
WW = 1/2 (LL - Transpose[LL]);
U = MatrixPower[Transpose[F].F, 1/2];
R = F.Inverse[U];
Ω = Simplify[D[R, t].Transpose[R]];
λ = 1;
μ = 1;
```

Now Ω is a 2 x 2 matrix with variable t. When I directly specify the form of σ, and I can get the problem solved:

```
σ = ({{σx[t], σxy[t]},{σyx[t], σy[t]}});
sol = NDSolve[{
    D[σ, t] == (λ*Tr[DD])*IdentityMatrix[2] + 2 μ*DD + Ω.σ + σ.Transpose[Ω],
    (σ /. t -> 0) == ({{0, 0}, {0, 0}})
  },
 {σx, σy, σxy, σyx},
 {t, 0, 5}]
```

However, if I try to define `{σx[t], σxy[t]},{σyx[t], σy[t]}}` as a single `σ[t]`, which is more elegant, there will be problem:

```
Clear[σ];
func[X_?ArrayQ] := (λ*Tr[DD])*IdentityMatrix[2] + 2 μ*DD + Ω.X + X.Transpose[Ω];
sol = NDSolve[{
    D[σ[t], t] == func[σ][t]], 
    σ[0] == ({{0, 0},{0, 0}})
  }, σ, {t, 0, 5}]
```

The problem lays in the fact that the variable t in matrix Ω is not treated as the same as the t inside the `NDSolve`. Can you help me fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let everything that depend on `t` actually take `t` as argument, `func` especially:

```
Clear[t, F, LL, WW, U, Ω, λ, μ, R, DD]
F[t_] = {{1, t}, {0, 1}};
LL[t_] = D[F[t], t].Inverse[F[t]];
DD[t_] = 1/2 (LL[t] + Transpose[LL[t]]);
WW[t_] = 1/2 (LL[t] - Transpose[LL[t]]);
U[t_] = MatrixPower[Transpose[F[t]].F[t], 1/2];
R[t_] = F[t].Inverse[U[t]];
Ω[t_] = Simplify[D[R[t], t].Transpose[R[t]]];
λ = 1;
μ = 1;

Clear[σ];
func[X_?ArrayQ, t_] := 
   (λ*Tr[DD[t]])*IdentityMatrix[2] + 2 μ*DD[t] + Ω[t].X + X.Transpose[Ω[t]];
sol = NDSolve[{σ'[t] == func[σ[t], t], σ[0] == {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}}
  , σ
  , {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: It works, great! I first expect that I will need to use some Hold-like-command to treat the variable t in different parts of the code. Your code solves it all, thanks!

Comment: I have an additional question: Since σxy and σyx are identical, can we just tell Mathematica this and thus accelerate the calculation?

Comment: Add: I mean still using the compact way of expressing the equation.